# ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental

Tags: npm, autorest

I am new to node and npm and trying to understand AutoRest.

When I type

```
autorest --list-available
```

into powershell ISE
I get

```
AutoRest code generation utility [version: 2.0.4262; node: v10.1.0]
(C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation.
https://aka.ms/autorest
autorest : (node:12580) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
At line:1 char:1
+ autorest --list-available
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ((node:12580) Ex...is experimental:String) [], RemoteExc 
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

 Extension Name                 Version       

 @microsoft.azure/autorest-core 2.0.4278       
 @microsoft.azure/autorest-core 2.0.4277       
 @microsoft.azure/autorest-core 2.0.4276       
 @microsoft.azure/autorest-core 2.0.4275       
 @microsoft.azure/autorest-core 2.0.4274       
 @microsoft.azure/autorest-core 2.0.4272       
 @microsoft.azure/autorest-core 2.0.4271       
 @microsoft.azure/autorest-core 2.0.4269       
 @microsoft.azure/autorest-core 2.0.4263       
 @microsoft.azure/autorest-core 2.0.4262       
Failure:
TypeError: volume[member].bind is not a function
TypeError: volume[member].bind is not a function
    at patchFilesystem 
(C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\autorest\dist\static-loader.js:277:43)
    at C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\autorest\dist\static-loader.js:281:18
    at Object.global.staticloader.undo 
(C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\autorest\dist\static-loader.js:163:7)
    at process.exit.n [as exit] 
(C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\autorest\dist\static-loader.js:170:27)
    at main (C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\autorest\dist\app.js:153:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:12580) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, close
    at Object.fs.closeSync (fs.js:529:3)
    at StaticVolumeFile.shutdown 
(C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\autorest\dist\static-loader.js:352:10)
    at StaticFilesystem.shutdown 
(C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\autorest\dist\static-loader.js:406:17)
    at process.exit.n [as exit] 
(C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\autorest\dist\static-loader.js:169:11)
    at main (C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\autorest\dist\app.js:239:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:12580) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated 
either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise 
which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12580) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the 
future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero
```

what is happening?
    exit code.

Comment: Why does this have a `powershell` tag..?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 good point. fixed it.

Comment: It gives you an error code: `node:12580`.  Additionally, you can do `$Error[0] | Format-List -Property * -Force` to see the full error record for your command.

Comment: It looks like the `AutoRest` package isn't following best-practices and leaving unhandled errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The module `autorest` uses new `fs` syntax, that instead of callbacks uses Promises. This is however not yet stable and therefore is the warning. Nothing really to worry about, unless you want to use it in production. But even then, as long as you update autorest with node together no problems should occur.

As for the error, it may be something in your configs. Try to make minimal error sample and post an issue to autorest git.

Comment: As an added note, since (s?)he is launching it from `powershell`, use `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` to suppress the error.  `powershell` has both terminating and non-terminating errors.  Alternatively, `2>$null` at the end of the command.

Answer (score 29):

Updating to the latest node version (v12.6+) removes the warning.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, you can safely ignore this warning.
If you want to suppress it (and all warnings), run your script with `node --no-warnings` instead of `node`.

In your example:

```
node --no-warnings `which autorest`
```

Comment: Absolutely shocking that in almost 2019 their file system support is still "experimental".

Comment: The filesystem API itself isn't experimental - the promise-based one is (because it is relatively new and its public interface might change).

Comment: so is it safe to use at production? Any alternative for this?

Comment: Safe to use but I'm looking for a way to disable it without specifying startup param every time.

Comment: This warning disappears with most recent node version (tried with v12.6.0)

Answer (score 15):

I was at `node@^10.15.1` which is an older version so I update it to `12.16.1` or `12.16.2` and it got fixed.

Answer (score 8):

I Was at `node@10.16.1` and I update it to `12.18.2`and it got fixed!

Answer (score 4):

It might have because you have updated the npm version but not the node version.
I updated the npm version from 6.3.0 to 7.16.0 [latest at this time], but was still using 11.3.0 for the node. To fix this version, I updated node to the latest LTS, i.e. 14.17.0 [LTS at this time].

```
nvm install 14.17.0 // Check for the LTS
nvm use 14.17.0
nvm alias default 14.17.0
```

Comment: This worked great for me. I substituted with 14.18.1 since that was the latest when I found my way to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Angular `10` that's just a warning when serving your code, which you can ignore as of today.

Comment: Why can we ignore it? I can't find anything else regarding this warming besides your post.

Comment: @Noppey it simply didn't affect my build, that's my personal conclusion if you're working with Angular.